# php how can get and download image from feelgrafix

Tags: php

i want to download image from this url 
http://feelgrafix.com/959413-rococo.html
and this the source image 
http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/28/959413-rococo.jpg 
but when i download image from this source 
file Download page url not download source image 
this the code i used it

```
    $url     = 'http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/28/959413-rococo.jpg';
$ch = curl_init($imgURL);
$fp = fopen('image.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

and this Other way

```
$content = file_get_contents($url); file_put_contents('sadsdasd.jpg',$content);
```

i think that this the protect from server .. 
no one can download OR see the image direct before open the page home

so what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using curl function i recommend you to user `file_get_content($url)` to fetch the file and `file_put_contents($path)` to save it in your desired path and in case if any error it throws just usin @ before both the function.

Comment: when i use file_get_content($url) the server return me to home page and get it Instead of image

Comment: have you use the "@" sign before both the function as shown belo
`@file_get_contents($url);`
`@file_put_contents($path)`;

Comment: use the below code

`$url="<your url to image>";
$content=@file_get_contents($url);
$putFile=@file_put_contents("<full path to the location with image name>",$content);`

i hope this might help you

Comment: My friend the problem is not solved yet 
php Code DOWNLOAD home page instead of the desired image directly
"@" sign Hide any Error .. but this not Error this Protect in server OR Script
can't download and view image Direct 
so can you see this image ? 
http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/28/959413-rococo.jpg
really you can't .. page redirect you to home 
how can i download this image by PHP ???

Comment: Knowing that this the real image source 
http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/28/959413-rococo.jpg

Comment: i have tried the and successfully fetch the image using the below code
`$url="http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/28/959413-rococo.jpg";
 $content=@file_get_contents($url);
 $putFile=@file_put_contents('image1.jpg',$content);
 var_dump($putFile);`

Comment: This is the final output of your code
http://tegypt.net/image1.jpg
If you download the picture and show the source will found that he has got the home page , not the true image of the required

Comment: I have checked it and instead of downloading the image it download the full page html. which makes me believe that the site is using URL rewriting.

Comment: Yes, this is the question .. Is there a solution to this problem?